# Installing apr(apt-get install libapr1-dev libssl-dev) in my linux system giving me errors

Tags: debian, apt, apr

Because of some security problems I am moving to Apache 7 from Apache 6. I am trying to install apr packages in my linux machine.
I am using the following command to install apr.

```
apt-get install libapr1-dev libssl-dev
```

which is giving me the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapr1 libssl-doc uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapr1 libapr1-dev libssl-dev libssl-doc uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,421 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.1e-2+deb7u14
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libssl-doc all 1.0.1e-2+deb7u14
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Err http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main libapr1 amd64 1.4.6-3+deb7u1
  Connection failed [IP: 212.27.32.66 80]
Err http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main uuid-dev amd64 1.4.6-3+deb7u1
  Connection failed [IP: 212.27.32.66 80]
Err http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main libapr1-dev amd64 1.4.6-3+deb7u1
  Connection failed [IP: 212.27.32.66 80]
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: That's an installation of Debian Wheezy that hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: My Debian server is not updated for a while.. So I have updated my Debian server(Linux 13) and run the above command.. This time i am able to install apr. . It may help someone. .

Answer (score 4):

The package lists `apt-get` is using are out of date; you need to run

```
apt-get update
```

before installing your packages. The connection errors to `ftp.fr.debian.org` are strange, that site is accessible for me...